# How do I parse data from a website that requires a login using javascript? (For a Pebble app)

Tags: javascript, pebble-watch, cloudpebble

I want to make an app for the Pebble that allows checking of grades from the watch, but I don't know how to use JavaScript to parse the grades website. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What is the grades website?

Comment: homeaccess.kellerisd.net/HomeAccess/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this site, but I've got the traditional `user:password@yoursite.com` to work via the **cloudpebble** emulator.  *Issues* are your password is *in clear text*, and I've not got around the iPhone security prompt as iPhone requires user intervention. This is to prevent phishing fraud. Android may be a different story.